# How to prevent replaceWith from making mutiple text nodes?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, replacewith

I have this piece of html code:

```
<p><span>h</span><span>o</span><span>l</span><span>a</span></p>
```

And I'm using the jQuery on it to replace all the spans:

```
$('p span').each(function(){
   $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());     
});
```

When I look into my DOM I see the script created **4 text nodes**, for each letter one. **How can I prevent this from happening?** I only want **1** text node!

Note: the given example is very very simplified. 
I'm actually doing it on:

```
<p>This is an <b>example</b>: <span>h</span><span>o</span><span>l</span><span>a</span>!</p>
```

That should look like:

```
<p>{text}This is an {/text}<b>{text}example{/text}</b>{text}: hola!{/text}</p>
```

{text} is a DOM-text node :-)

Comment: Is changing the HTML an option?

Comment: You mean like p.html(p.html())? Would be very very heavy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is at the end, call the native [`normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.normalize) method:

```
$('p').find('span').each(function(){
   $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());     
}).end()[0].normalize();
```

**EDIT:** I was previously using [`parent()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)  to traverse up from the `<span>` elements, but they were removed from the DOM, so they no longer had a parent.

Instead now I first select the `<p>`, then [`find()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the `<span>` elements. This way I can use [`end()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/end/) to get back to the `<p>`, and call `.normalize()`.

If there are several `<p>` elements, you'll want to do another loop.

```
$('p').find('span').each(function(){
   $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());     
}).end().each(function() {
    this.normalize();
});
```

---

You could also pass a function as a parameter to [`replaceWith()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) which returns the text of each element.

```
$('p').find('span').replaceWith(function(i,el){ 
    return $.text([this]);
}).end().each(function() {
    this.normalize();
});
```

Comment: @Kees: I've got it. The call to `.parent()` is wrong because the `<span>` elements were replaced and no longer have a parent. Updating...

Comment: @PatrickDw Yes! It works with the end()[0].normalize(). Now I'm looking into what has the best performance of your examples :-).

Comment: @Kees: Probably the last one, or the combination of the first and last one if you don't need the second `.each()`. In other words, the last would end with `.end()[0].normalize()`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you really want this?

```
$('p').text(function (i, txt) {
    return txt;
});
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/2qNGY/

Comment: +1 I like this, though I'd probably pass a function  instead `$('p').text(function(i,txt){return txt;});`

Comment: I would loose other html present in the P... so this wouldn't work I think... and .html(html()) would be very very heavy

Comment: @Kees, fair enough. I didn't see other HTML in your question so I assumed it would be ok.